# Pandas Dataframe aggregate different groups of columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
[np.random.randint(1,10,8),
np.random.randint(1,10,8),
np.random.randint(1,10,8),
np.random.randint(1,10,8)]).T

# left col is the index
>> a  b  c  d group
0  5  6  3  2    g1
1  5  6  6  6    g1
2  3  9  5  3    g1
3  5  6  8  2    g1
4  2  2  9  6    g1
5  9  5  4  8    g2
6  1  3  5  2    g2
7  3  8  8  6    g2
```

I want to groupby "group" column and then do a few different operations:

• For column "a" I want to get the min and max value

• For the rest I want to sum them

```
min_max_col = ['a']
sum_cols = ['b','c','d']
```

Is there a simple way to do this?
The result should look something like this:

```
>>   min  max  sum_b  sum_c  sum_d
g1    2    5     29     48     19
g2    1    9     16     48     16
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use agg

```
df = df.groupby('group').agg({'a':[ np.min,  np.max], 'b': np.sum, 'c': np.sum, 'd': np.sum})
df.columns = ['min', 'max', 'sum_b', 'sum_c', 'sum_d']
df = df.reset_index()


    group   min max sum_b   sum_c   sum_d
0   g1      2   5   29      31      19
1   g2      1   9   16      17      16
```

Comment: got it this answers it

Comment: @RSHAP That would depend on the actual use case (how you determine the columns etc) but you can do something like `dict.fromkeys(list('bcd'), 'sum')`

Comment: You can specify all the operations separately, the way PiRsquared did and then pass that function. It would improve readability when there are a lot of columns but won't reduce the work

Comment: yep yep ^ realized this when I asked haha

Answer (score 3):

This is different because we are leveraging pandas internally referenced `sum`, `min`, and `max` functions.  It is my opinion that we should leverage those as much as possible.

```
f = dict(
    a=['min', 'max'],
    b='sum',
    c='sum',
    d='sum'
)

df.groupby('group').agg(f)

        a       b   c   d
      min max sum sum sum
group                    
g1      2   5  29  31  19
g2      1   9  16  17  16
```